# How to change the x axis and y axis labels in ggplot2 box plots in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I plotted 4 different box plot charts in the same graph. I want to change the x axis and y axis labels.

I want to change the **RSQ_STB_BMI** to BMI and I want to change **T1_SB_OSA** to T1
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKnTh.png)
This is my script,

```
db1<- dt %>% 
  dplyr::select("RSQ_STB_BMI","T1_SB_OSA","T2_SB_OSA","T3_SB_OSA","PP_SB_OSA") 

db1 %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -RSQ_STB_BMI) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(value), RSQ_STB_BMI, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_boxplot() + ggtitle('Boxplot of BMI by the Risk of Sleep Apnea')+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#97e095','#4c9f83','#1c4f60'))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+facet_grid(~factor(variable, levels=c("T1_SB_OSA","T2_SB_OSA","T3_SB_OSA","PP_SB_OSA")),switch = "both")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

```
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside")`
```

Comment: `labs(x = "T1", y = "BMI")`?

Comment: Thank you. But it only changes the Y axis. Since this graph has 4 different categorical variables it does not change the lables of the X axis.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to modify the strip labels, not the x-axis title, you can do this in `facet_wrap` like so:

```
## example data:

df  <-  data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:4],
                   xs = 1:4,
                   ys = 1:4
                   )
```

```
df |> ggplot(aes(x = xs, y = ys)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ group, 
             strip.position = 'bottom', ## switch is deprecated
             labeller = as_labeller(\(label) paste('category', label))
             )
```

[image: facet wrap with custom strip labels]

... or, fully neglecting the original facet labels:

```
df |> ggplot(aes(x = xs, y = ys)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ group, 
             strip.position = 'bottom', ## switch is deprecated
             labeller = as_labeller(\(x) c('spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter'))
             )
```

[image: fully custom labels]